# Integrate Ember-widgets Highchart in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, ember.js, highcharts, flask, jinja2

I'm working with Flask, [Ember-widgets](http://addepar.github.com/#/ember-widgets/) and [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/). My question is, is possible have in a same template (then, this template is run in jinja2) Ember-widgets and Highchart without using [`Ember.Object.extend`](http://jsfiddle.net/M844s/)? This is because for Ember, in the template, I need put `{% raw %}` and I can't pass an argument from flask using the line below:

```
return render_template('plot.html', data = array_values)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to keep your *whole* template in a `{% raw %}` container; you can mix and match:

```
{% raw %}
{{#accordion-component}}
  {{#accordion-item isActive=true title="Foo Bar"}}
{% endraw %}
    This is text in an accordion, with a 
    <a href="{{ url_for('blah') }}">link elsewhere</a>.
{% raw %}
  {{/accordion-item}}
  {{#accordion-item title="Bar Baz"}}
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit...
  {{/accordion-item}}
{{/accordion-component}}
{% endraw %}
```

You can selectively insert angle-bracketed instructions with interpolation too; the following is *not* a raw section:

```
{{ '{{' }}#popover-link-component tagName="button"
    class="btn btn-primary" title="{{ popover_title }}"
    content="{{ popover_content }}" {{ '}}' }}
    {{ 
{{ '{{/popover-link-component}}' }}
```

Here the `{{..}}` angle brackets around the popover component are inserted by Jinja2 instructions, the closing tag is one string interpolation.